# NGINX - redirect from https to http without ssl certificate

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up a new nginx box however I can't figure out why my nginx isn't starting when I use this:

```
    server {
    listen      443;
    server_name mysite.com; // https://mysite.com
    rewrite ^(.*)   https://mynewsite.com.com$1 permanent; // new site
}
```

Anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean 'without ssl certificate'? You can't host secure connections without a certificate at all - the SSL connection is negotiated first before the web server gets a chance to organise the redirect.

Comment: I believe with apache's htaccess you can redirect from ssl to nonssl but I may be wrong, just hoping there is a way to do this

Comment: You are declaring a HTTPS web server. Nginx cannot accept SSL connections without SSL certificate.

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible to do. Redirecting from https to http itself is based on a successful https connection, which requires a certificate.

Comment: this information is very useful and important to know

Comment: So you can't redirect or rewrite the address from https if it infact isn't actually supposed to be https?

Answer (score -4):

if you have an SSL either purchased one or self signed SSL, you can then redirect the https to http. yes, you can redirect https to http without SSL if someone try adding the **s** letter in your url so that your url can't serve anything over HTTPS, but only HTTP

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name yourdomain.com;
    return 301 http://www.yourdomain.com;
}
```

and you need to have another server block to complete the **www** servingon your url.

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name www.yourdomain.com;
        // the rest of your configs //
    }
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer doesn't have anything about the redirect.

Comment: I tried this with other https vhosts, but it made the other vhosts on same server not work, so no recomended.

Comment: As I understand this makes nginx consider port 443 an HTTP port. HTTPS will fail.